# How to update multiple rows based on select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I might be overlooking something very obvious but I cannot get my multiple `UPDATE` statement to run. What I want to achieve is to `SELECT` an `AVG()` value from a table and `UPDATE` a column based on these values in another table.

I followed the following solution, but could not make it run:

[Orginal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server/8963158#8963158)

my solution:

```
UPDATE
  teams
SET
  teams.overall_rank = q.rank_avg
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      team_id as t_id,
      AVG(rank) as rank_avg
    FROM
      team_list
    WHERE
      rank NOT IN (0, -1)
    GROUP BY
      team_id
    ORDER BY
      rank_avg
  ) q
WHERE
  q.t_id = teams.team_id
```

The error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'FROM ( SELECT team_id as t_id, AVG(rank) as rank_avg FR' at line 5
```

I am using MySQL. What am I missing here?

Comment: The answer link that you refer to is an `UPDATE` query for **MS-SQL** (you can see the tag). ;)

Comment: that was the obvious thing I missed. I read mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below - your syntax is not valid for mysql

```
UPDATE teams
join
  (
    SELECT
      team_id as t_id,AVG(rank) as rank_avg
      FROM team_list
      WHERE rank NOT IN (0, -1)
      GROUP BY team_id
   ) q on q.t_id = teams.team_id 
SET teams.overall_rank = q.rank_avg
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a join:

```
UPDATE teams t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      team_id as t_id,
      AVG(rank) as rank_avg
    FROM team_list
    WHERE rank NOT IN (0, -1)
    GROUP BY team_id
) q ON q.t_id = t.team_id 
SET t.overall_rank = q.rank_avg
```

The ORDER BY in the subquery is not needed.

Comment: You were a minute faster than @fa06, so I accepted you answer :)

Comment: @JoeBe its seems you are wrong becauses fa06 is 36seconds faster than the forpas so your logic is wrong here

Comment: You are right! I did not hover over the time but it displayed 10min for forpas and 11min for fa06... strange. I adjust it